# Show the default value chosen for XX:ParallelGCThreads

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection

I'm tuning the JVM of Java 8 and I'm trying to know what value was defined for the parameter `-XX:ParallelGCThreads`. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40972_01/doc.70/e40973/cnf_jvmgc.htm#autoId2) says:

> **-XX:ParallelGCThreads**: Sets the number of threads used during parallel phases of the garbage collectors. The default value varies with the platform on which the JVM is running.

I would like to know what value was defined in my platform and if I need to change that. I don't have in this environment a JDK available, only the JRE.

Comment: @the8472, thanks for the help! `jinfo` is from JDK I supposed. I have only JRE in the environment.

Comment: It appears you have not thoroughly read the linked answer. jinfo is only mentioned as an alternative

Comment: @the8472 I see now. But the accepted answer here is more detailed in explaining how to use it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Default value :

```
 java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | grep ParallelGCThreads
 uint  ParallelGCThreads                        = 4
```

If you have a running process `jinfo <processId>`, if it's not present in the output, it is using the default value (look under `VM Flags`)

Comment: adding the `-version` parameter might be necessary: `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep ParallelGCThreads`

Comment: On some JVMs the output is wring to stderr, so redirecting the stderr is required for the grep:
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal 2>&1 | grep ParallelGCThreads

Answer (score 5):

Consider the default is a fixed number *N*, as in `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=<N>`

As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html), that number is based on the amount of HW threads your system has:

> On a machine with N hardware threads where N is greater than 8, the parallel collector uses a fixed fraction of N as the number of garbage collector threads. The fraction is approximately 5/8 for large values of N. At values of N below 8, the number used is N.